# Confusion matrix of UNET image sgemenation model

Tags: deep-learning, model-evaluations, confusion-matrix, image-segmentation, f1score

I have used Unet model for image segmentation. I have used RGB images and corresponding image masks and at output i got corresponding region of interest. Now i want to find confusion matrix of this model and from this i want to evaluate other parameters. Can some help? I could not get what are predicted and actual values which are required to build confusion matrix. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your masks have only one channel and in the case of binary segmentation, you can easily compute a confusion matrix from one image thanks to:

- **TP**: ground truth and predicted pixel are of class 1 (object)
- **TN**: ground truth and predicted pixel are of class 0 (background)
- **FP**: ground truth pixel=0 while predicted pixel=1
- **FN**: ground truth pixel=1 while predicted pixel=0

On a dataset, you can get the confusion matrix from chosen iou thresholds.
For example if your iou threshold is 0.5:

- **TP += 1** for each image where iou(ground_truth, predicted) >= 0.5
- **FP += 1** for each image where iou(ground_truth, predicted) < 0.5 and predicted != empty
- **FN += 1** for each image where iou(ground_truth, predicted) < 0.5 and gt != empty

It is just a suggestion, there is maybe better ways to deal with that.